# How to update permalink programmatically?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

After activating my plugin I should go to `settings -> permalinks` and click on the Save button to make custom endpoints ( for my-account page ) work. How can I do it programmatically? ( I used `flush_rewrite_rules` but it didn't work. )

Comment: Where/when did you call `flush_rewrite_rules`? Keep in mind that this function shouldn't be called on every page load as it changes the database, can you include the code you used to try this?

Comment: The problem was not flush_rewrite_rules .
Problem caused from :
Instead of adding custom endpoint one time on activation, i was doing it everytime. So one time flush_rewrite_rules could not handle it.

Comment: can you post your solution as an answer along with the change you made in code? Comments can't be marked as the correct answer or upvoted for points

Answer (score 0):

`flush_rewrite_rules` should only be called on the plugin activation OR after you update or add rewrite rules programatically.

If it does not work after verifying this, there is some other issue on your site.  Make sure you are not calling `flush_rewrite_rules` in constructor or somewhere else on every page load.